# How can i setup and configure sendmail SMTP server to send bulk emails in UBUNTU?

Tags: email, smtp, sendmail

I am working on an assignment in which i have to send bulk emails with sendmail SMTP server.
I have tries many tutorial to setup sendmail server to send bulk emails but nothing helps me.
Can anyone tells the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial ripped straight from : https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/

It uses Apache2, PHP5, PostFix and SquirrelMail.

In a terminal type :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install apache2 php5 postfix dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d squirrelmail -y && sudo ervice postfix restart && sudo service dovecot restart && sudo squirrelmail-configure && sudo cp /etc/squirrelmail/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/squirrelmail.conf && sudo a2ensite squirrelmail.conf
```

[image: say ok]

choose internet site :
[image: choose internet site]

enter qualifier domain name of your choosing :
[image: enter domain name]

for dovecot you'll have to accept the self-signed certificate :
[image: accept self-signed certificate]

enter hostname, ("localhost") : 
[image: enter localhost]

type "2" :

[image: choose 2]

now type "1" : here you'll have to enter your domain name (you need a domain name)
[image: type one and enter domain name]

Go back to the main menu by writing “R” and hitting the enter key, write “4” in order to configure the general options. You see “Allow server-side sorting”? Enter “11” and change it from “false” to “true” by entering “y”. Now hit the Enter key, and enter the “S” key in order to save the configuration file :
[image: R then 4]

In order to start using squirrelmail webmail, you’ll have to create a new user, to do so, run.

```
sudo useradd myusername
```

Replace “myusername” with the user name you want, create a password for the new user by running.

```
sudo passwd myusername
```

Create a home folder for the user in /var/www/html/myusername and make it default home directory.

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/myusername
usermod -m -d /var/www/html/myusername myusername
```

then add rights to this newly created user :

```
sudo chown -R myusername:myusername /var/www/html/myusernam
```

now you can open up a new tab in your browser and you can go to the domain name you entered + `/squirrelmail`.

it will show this :

[image: squirrelmail sscreenshot]

go ahead and log in with the newly creeated account.

[image: squirellmail logged in]

now you should be able to bombard your mails.